# Deleting VLAN on Cisco 887

Tags: cisco, vlan

How can I delete a VLAN config from a Cisco 887VA with IOS 15.3?

For some testing I have created VLAN2 and no longer need it but now I can't get rid of it from `show running-config`.

From config mode I tried:

- `interface vlan 2` → `shutdown`
- `no vlan 2`
- `write mem`

But even after reload the VLAN is still showing up `running-config`.

Not that it's a big issue but it's polluting the config...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`no vlan 2` deletes VLAN 2 from the VLAN database. If you want to delete the VLAN2 SVI, you need to type `no interface vlan2`.

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of the Cisco IOS for 87x routers have the vlan 2 hardcoded, you cannot delete it!

```
Router(config)#no vlan 2
%Default VLAN 2 may not be deleted.
Router(config)#
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways how to do it.

**1.)** Check the whole configuration of SVI Vlan 2 - is there command switchport access vlan 2 ? If yes, just change it to default - switchport access vlan 1, then remove vlan 2 again and verify via show vlan command.

**2.)** If you are using only default Vlans 1 and 1002 - 1005 you can just delete the whole vlan.dat from flash and reload the switch. This will delete your unwanted Vlan for sure.

Comment: There is no vlan.dat on Cisco routers, only on switches.

Comment: @Elektordi You may want to look at Routers with integrated switches, such as the 880 and 890 series, and then revise your comment. They do have vlan.dat files.

Comment: Just tested on a C1111 router with integrated switch, there is indeed a vlan.dat, you are right... Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone looks for an answer relating to a similar router.

Some Cisco devices use the VLAN database.

```
router#vlan database

% Warning: It is recommended to configure VLAN from config mode,
  as VLAN database mode is being deprecated. Please consult user
  documentation for configuring VTP/VLAN in config mode.

! Once in the VLAN database you can then delete the VLANs you no longer need.

router(vlan)#no vlan 2

router(vlan)#apply

router(vlan)#exit
```

That will remove the VLAN

To view VLANS you may need to use the `show vlan-switch brief` command, that will show you all the VLANs that have been configured on the device.

Comment: That is true for very old devices and mostly routers with switch-port linecards.